# How to determine the incoming request nature in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Lets say I have incoming url

`/writer/$category`

It's `Route` it written as

`Route::get('/writer/{category}', ['uses' => 'WriterController@index']);`

Now how to determine in Controller that whether the `category` is string or integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type with `gettype` function, like this:

```
dd(gettype($value));
```

at your controller

Comment: What is `dd` in this?

Comment: like `if($value == string){}elseif($value==int){}`

Comment: dd is a method of Laravel to stop the execution and print the result, is to debug purposes, take a look of method documentation http://php.net/manual/es/function.gettype.php @Wayne